# Como separar palavras de texto de uma coluna com vírgulas?

Tags: firebird

Existe uma função pronta no Firebird 2.5 que seja o inverso da função list?

Quando você faz um

```
select list(campo,',') from tabela
```

é retornado todos os valores do campo em uma linha só separados por vírgula, eu queria uma função que separasse o campo `varchar` em diversas colunas

```
tabelax
codigo      informacao
 1          'alfa, beta, gama'
 2          'delta, peta, omega'
```

ao fazer o `select codigo,comando(informacao,',') as inf from tabelax` ele retorne:

```
codigo  inf
  1     alfa
  1     beta
  1     gama
  2     delta
  2     peta
  2     omega
```

Comment: Operações de pivot e unpivot , achei isto (https://www.mail-archive.com/firebird-support@yahoogroups.com/msg06635.html) no Google

Comment: desculpe, mas ou e não compreendi o funcionamento do pivot ou ele não faz o que eu nessecito

Comment: No caso seria o unpivot, o exemplo lá de fato não é bom, este post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064313/how-to-do-a-sql-grouping-by-multiple-columns-including-days ) pode te ajudar

Comment: pelo que entendi o pivot/unpivot é pra converter linha pra coluna e vice versa.
e esse comando tbm não é suportado pelo firebird.

Comment: Sim, mas você acha páginas que citam como simular para Firebird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

infelizmente o firebird não possui um comando para isso necessitando a criação de uma StoreProcedure para fazer isso  é necessário criar uma strore procedure e usa-lá no sql.

Exemplo:

```
set term ^ ;

create or alter procedure f_retorna_lista(in_id integer,in_lista varchar(550))
returns (out_id integer, out_str varchar(100) )
as
declare variable var_pos integer;
declare variable var_next_pos integer;
declare variable var_length integer;
begin
  var_length = char_length(:in_lista);
  var_pos = 1;
  while (var_pos <= var_length) do
  begin
  var_next_pos = position(',',:in_lista,:var_pos);
  if (:var_next_pos = 0) then
    var_next_pos = var_length+1;
  out_str = trim(substring(:in_lista from :var_pos for (:var_next_pos - :var_pos)));
  out_id = in_id;
  suspend;
  var_pos = var_next_pos+1;
  end
end^
```

onde eu executava `select t.codigo, sp.out_str from tabelax t left join (f_retorna_lista(codigo,informacao)) sp on sp.out_id = t.codigo`